# Is it possible to utilize Incremental Static Regeneration on platforms other than Vercel?

Tags: azure, next.js, static-site-generation

I am using Next.js with Static Site Generation. I would like to add Incremental Static Regeneration to my application and host it on a cloud platform.

Is it possible to use ISR on other platforms than Vercel ( like Azure, AWS etc.)? I have been trying to deploy my application on Azure but the ISR doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm also having this issue

Answer (score 2):

We have been doing quite some work in this direction as described in the blog post https://www.sergevandenoever.nl/nextjs-on-azure-and-sitecore/ and the series of posts referenced from that post by my colleague Erwin Smit. We run the ISR in an Azure function, in combination with Azure CDN. This can be found in the GitHub repo https://github.com/macaw-cad/nextjs-on-azure. Due to deprecation of the proxy functionality in Azure Functions (we depend on version 3, proxies is removed in version 4, version 3 will be deprecated in December), we are currently rethinking how to implement ISR on Azure.